# For Madhwists, is there a hierarchy even among souls that have achieved Moksha?

Tags: madhwa

In the book

Srivaishnava and Dvaita Vedanta Polemics
and Interpretations of the Ramayana
as a Bhakti Text

Cameron M Wright says

> The Dvaita view also asserts a strong distinctness and hierarchy
> among human souls, which persists even after
> the attainment of moksha

Can this assertion of Wright be supported by Dvaita scripture?

Comment: yes, true. Read An Introduction to Madhva Vedanta by Deepak Sharma, he is not only a scholar, but a practising madhava vedantin. He learned madhava teaching from authorized Madhava Math. The book is very good.

Comment: https://www.amazon.in/Introduction-Madhva-Vedanta-Ashgate-Philosophies/dp/0754606376

Comment: So you are not questioning here but passing opinion about other philosophy

Comment: fixed it @PrasannaR